# Facebook application to view posts on Twitter feed

Tags: facebook

There are Facebook applications that allow Facebook users to tweet directly on Facebook, by delivering the post to their accounts through Twitter servers.

Are there similar applications that allow Facebook users to view all posts on the Twitter feed of their account (or alternatively, all tweets by a specific Twitter user) directly on their Facebook news feed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [IFFTT](https://ifttt.com)? There you can create tweets based on your facebook updates